# Line chart auto scaling

Tags: javascript, charts, google-visualization

I'm using google visualization charts in my grails app. I'm using line chart to present some data but it behaves oddly when I add alot rows to data here are screens [image: screen1][image: screen2]

how could I prevent such scalling ? I woudl like to scalling be the same when i have alot data and none data. I don't mean the length of chart because its natural it gets bigger when I add more data, but size of labels `hAxis` labels and vAxis label is getting bigger without reason
here is how I created chart

```
    visualization.draw(visualization_data, {width: 55840, title: 'Wykres wydajno\u015Bci', vAxis: {textPosition: 'in'}, hAxis: {direction: 1, slantedText: true, slantedTextAngle: 90}, pointSize: 10, chartArea: {top: 10, width: '50%', height: '50%', left: 10}, legend: {position: 'right'}});
```

and styling

```
        #linechart {
        overflow-x: scroll;
        overflow-y: hidden; 
        width: 100%;
        height: 500px;
    }
```

Comment: will you please post the current config options being used? also, are the values on the xAxis `'date'` or `'string'`? not able to reproduce...

Comment: @WhiteHat, yes date is a string, i have added chart options to the post, if you need something more please tell

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use the `textStyle` option on both axis' to set the `fontSize`

```
textStyle: {
  fontSize: 12
}
```

see following working snippet...

(but `width: 55840` seems too wide??)

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  callback: function () {
    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    data.addColumn('date', 'Date');
    data.addColumn('number', '2005');
    data.addColumn('number', '2006');
    data.addRows([
       [new Date('01/01/2016'), 200, 210],
       [new Date('01/02/2016'), 190, 220],
       [new Date('01/03/2016'), 205, 200],
       [new Date('01/04/2016'), 220, 230],
       [new Date('01/05/2016'), 212, 210],
       [new Date('01/06/2016'), 185, 193],
       [new Date('01/07/2016'), 196, 207],
       [new Date('01/08/2016'), 200, 210],
       [new Date('01/09/2016'), 190, 220],
       [new Date('01/10/2016'), 205, 200],
       [new Date('01/11/2016'), 220, 230],
       [new Date('01/12/2016'), 212, 210],
       [new Date('01/13/2016'), 185, 193],
       [new Date('01/14/2016'), 196, 207],
       [new Date('01/15/2016'), 200, 210],
       [new Date('01/16/2016'), 190, 220],
       [new Date('01/17/2016'), 205, 200],
       [new Date('01/18/2016'), 220, 230],
       [new Date('01/19/2016'), 212, 210],
       [new Date('01/20/2016'), 185, 193],
       [new Date('01/21/2016'), 196, 207],
       [new Date('01/22/2016'), 200, 210],
       [new Date('01/23/2016'), 190, 220],
       [new Date('01/24/2016'), 205, 200],
       [new Date('01/25/2016'), 220, 230],
       [new Date('01/26/2016'), 212, 210],
       [new Date('01/27/2016'), 185, 193],
       [new Date('01/28/2016'), 196, 207],
       [new Date('01/29/2016'), 200, 210],
       [new Date('01/30/2016'), 190, 220],
       [new Date('01/31/2016'), 205, 200]
    ]);

    var options = {
      width: 55840,
      height: 800,
      title: 'Wykres wydajno\u015Bci',
      vAxis: {
        textPosition: 'in',
        textStyle: {
          fontSize: 12
        }
      },
      hAxis: {
        direction: 1,
        slantedText: true,
        slantedTextAngle: 90,
        textStyle: {
          fontSize: 12
        }
      },
      pointSize: 10,
      chartArea: {top: 10, width: '50%', height: '50%', left: 10},
      legend: {position: 'right'}
    };

    var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('linechart'));
    chart.draw(data, options);
  },
  packages: ['corechart']
});
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="linechart"></div>
```

Comment: width is 130 * data.size() thats why it so big

Comment: it works like charm, any idea why font size has changed automaticly?